# c# creating grpah/chart by entering data. WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, graph, charts

So what I am trying to say, i have to create a WinForm, it should contain textboxes for entering data/points and a button that would create a graph. I have found a few usefull links, but can someone explain me how to do it because i stuck and dont know how to continue my working flow.

this one is for ASP, i tried the same with WinForms - does not work correctly http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbeniwal321/drawing-a-line-chart-in-gdi/

here is an example what i want to do - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9lNbu-3oBE

My apologize for broken English!

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this instead of winforms. The advanced DataBinding capabilities of WPF will make this task really simpler, compared to the amount of code required by the procedural, too-much-code-for-anything winforms approach. Not to mention that the Youtube video you linked to is a perfect example of the huge degradation of user experience caused by the horrible constant flickering exhibited by winforms when doing anything related to drawing, due to the lack of hardware acceleration.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code samples of things you tried and what didn't work about them? WinForms will handle this just fine if you don't want to deal with WPF.